# How can I get AWS CloudTrail event instance name using the instance Id?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to get the instance name of a CloudTrail event. I am extracting the instance ID from the event, but the event doesn't appear to have the hostname/instance name. To get the instance name, so I'm trying to pass the ID to `describe_instance` or some other function (I am not sure what that would be). In essence, I want to pass the ID and get the instance name from the instance tags.

I tried using `all_instances` but I am not sure how I can filter the results to get the name of the exact instance I need. This is what I have so far:

```
    inst = ec2.describe_instances(instanceidT)
    for tag in inst.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            instanceName= tag['Value'][enter image description here][1]
            print(instanceName+ "this is what I am looking for")
```

instanceidT has the instance ID i pulled from a cloud trail event

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the boto3 **resource** method to retrieve instance tags for a specific instance:

```py
import boto3

instance_id = 'i-abcd1234'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')  # Update accordingly
instance = ec2_resource.Instance(instance_id)
for tag in instance.tags:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
        instanceName= tag['Value']
        print(instanceName)
```

Here is the same thing using the **client** method:

```py
import boto3

instance_id = 'i-abcd1234'

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')  # Update accordingly
instances = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])

for reservation in instances['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        for tag in instance['Tags']:
            if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                instanceName= tag['Value']
                print(instanceName)
```